# Deriving differential equation satisfied by family of circles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

There's an exercise in *Differential Equations with Applications* by George Simmons which asks to derive the differential equation satisfied by the family of circles in the plane whose centers lie on the line $ y = x $ and are tangent to the $ x $ and $ y $ axes.

I've derived the general equation for this one-parameter family, $ (x - c)^2 + (y - c)^2 = c^2 $, with parameter $ c $. Using implicit differentiation, the curves also satisfy $ (x - c) + (y - c) y' = 0 $, which solves for $ c $ in terms of the other variables as $$ c = \frac{x + y y'}{1 + y'}. $$

I've tried substituting $ c $ into the first equation but I am unable to simplify the result. I feel like there is some trick or algebraic manipulation I am forgetting to arrive to the answer.

The official answer in the back of the book is $$ (x - y)^2 (1 + y'^2) = (x + y y')^2. $$ Mathematica confirms this so it's probably not an error. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your solution 
$$ c = \frac{x + y y'}{1 + y'} $$
it is straightforward to compute:
$$ \begin{aligned}
x-c & = y' \frac{x - y }{1 + y'} \\
 y-c &=  \frac{y-x }{1 + y'} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Now substitute in the implicit equation of the circles:
$$\begin{aligned}
(x-c)^2 &+(y-c)^2 &=& c^2 \\
(y')^2\,\left(\frac{x - y }{1 + y'}\right)^2 &+ \left(\frac{y-x }{1 + y'}\right)^2 &=& \left(\frac{x + y y'}{1+y'}\right)^2 
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on...